# Component based architecture - Rendering approach?

Tags: architecture, component-based

I'm planning to use a [component based architecture](http://www.gameprogrammingpatterns.com/component.html) for a new 3D game engine I plan to work on, however I don't know how to approach the rendering side of things.

I can see two options here:

- Every renderable game object has a `RenderComponent`, which stores a mesh and OpenGL-specific stuff like VBOs and VAOs. When the time comes to have `update()` called, it will use OpenGL to render itself.
- Every renderable game object has a `MeshComponent`. When it's time to render, the `Renderer` would go through a list of all `MeshComponent`s, extract vertex and material information, and render it.

Which option would be most flexible if I want to implement things like post-processing (bloom, motion blur), skyboxes, LOD, blending/transparency or implementing a deferred renderer?

Comment: Might interest you: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/47117/how-to-handle-materials-in-an-entity-component-system

Comment: @LukeB. That's a fantastic post, and it solved my question. If you're allowed to post that link as an answer, I'll mark it as solved. :)

Comment: Maybe you could explain your solution in an answer and accept that, I would love to see your interpretation of that answer :)